# jquery bootstrap typeahead cannot bind event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using twitter typeahead and I can't bind select event. I've seen almost everything related to this but it doesn't work yet.

```
var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
$('#search').typeahead({
    source: subjects
});

$('#search').bind('typeahead:select', function (ev, suggestion) {
    console.log('Selection: ' + suggestion);
});
```

Comment: Which specific typeahead library are you using? Could you link to their documentation?

Comment: I am using following. twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js

Comment: The Typeahead used in Bootstrap v2 (which is *very* out of date, and you should look at updating) does not raise any events when an option is selected. You could potentially attach a `change` event handler to the `#search` input, but this won't work in the exact manner you seem to be looking for. I'd strongly suggest you move to a more up to date typeahead library which has an event model, such as [this](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/)

Comment: Thank you. My issue is fixed by your suggestion. Best, Lee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by updating typeahead and the code above works well after updating.